# how to know what part of my application use the file

Tags: c#

In my application I scan images and creat a treeview and when I click on the name of file I show the image in imageViewer,

but when I use delete directory after that I clear the treeview and the imageviewer

```
treevImage.Nodes.Clear();
imageViewer.Image.Dispose();
imageViewer.Image = null;
Directory.Delete(localPath, true);
```

I got an exception that one image was used by another thread, the problem is that it is random, the first one or any other image!

> The process cannot access the file 'image9.tif' because it is being used by another process.

Is there a way to know which part of my application uses that image?

**Edit :**

When I add

```
imageViewer.Dispose();
```

l'app delete the files without exception but when I scan again I got exception when show a new image in imageViewer

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Edit 2:**

Exception do to dispose() was corrected by *MikeNakis* but now After I delete the directory I make a new scan and to show the new images in the imageViewer, after dispose() and new ; I can't see the new images for the new scan

Comment: show us the code where you open an image

Comment: Where do the threads come into play? The code you show doesn't use any threads, and you don't explain where you're using them in the question. Are you opening the images on separate threads? Also, remember that **a process is not the same as a thread**. Chances are, that error message is telling you that some other application is using the image, not some other part of *your* application.

Comment: @ Magnus :it's difficult to make the code, I read the scaned images (with virtual scanner) plus de 20 images and do a modifcation and read a bare code I use 4 class to manuplate it :/

Comment: @Cody Gray : sorry I edit the title I don't use thread, but it's part of my apolication how use the file,I can delete it manually just if I close my application

Comment: @Akrem make sure all streams to files are closed before you delete the directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have disposed the imageViewer with `imageViewer.Dispose();` you need to then re-create it with `imageViewer = new ImageViewer();`.

Comment: I make "imageViewer = new ImageViewer();" and ok I haven't an exception but I can't show my image also after that !

Comment: So, you want to keep the image visible after you have deleted the directory? Well then, it becomes a different issue. I am not sure what you should do, because I do not know what this ImageViewer is and exactly how it works. Can you tell me where I can see the documentation of ImageViewer?

Comment: No, After I delete the directory I make a new scan and show the new images in the imageViewer, after dispose() and new ; I can't see the new images for the new scan

Comment: I see. If this ImageViewer is a control, and it lives inside a form, then after recreating it you need to redo its initialization. Look inside the Form.Designer.cs file for the ImageViewer and copy the initialization. (Though this looks like a very clunky way of doing things: if I could see the documentation of ImageViewer I might be able to provide better help.)

Comment: ImageViewer  : a custom controle in it two other custom controle :/ ok I will try to do the initialization, and thx

Comment: thx it work, just I will wait if there's any other solution to not  initializing again.

Comment: Of course, there is no hurry. The bounty ends in 4 days; I would not expect you to accept anything before that time.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally have to wait a few ms after closing and disposing a file before it is available for reading on the same thread - just as you describe above. I solved this by writing a method which wait until I had exclusive access to the file.

```
File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
```

Remember to put a thread.sleep in that loop. If this locks up your program, you're forgetting to dispose something.

(I never investigated why this was required since the workaround was successful and has been in use for almost 10 year now. Could be a bug in my code, but since I was writing to the file before closing/disposing it I suspect that our anti-virus software placed a brief lock on the file)

Another solution is to prevent the image object locking the file at all. You can read the image file into a memory stream, and instantiate the image from it. Just ensure you do this right so that you don't end up copying the image around in memory more than neccessary.

Comment: Yes, problems like this are almost always caused by anti-virus applications. I like the memory stream solution better than `Thread.Sleep` in a loop...

Comment: Maybe, but in my situation I was streaming to a temporary file which was renamed when complete. If the file is locked you probably want to give it another 20-50ms before retrying anyway, so you won't see any CPU spikes caused by this loop.